# How to convert between pixels and coordinates in turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How many co-ordinates does one pixel cover? If I place a square of side 20, with its left side touching the origin (0,0), what will the coordinates of the bottom-right corner of the square be? I have attached a picture for visualization.

[image]

If one knows how much co-ordinate does one pixel cover in python turtle, this problem can easily be solved.

Comment: It probably depends on the resolution of your image.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the second sentence of the Python turtle documentation might answer your question:

> Imagine a robotic turtle starting at (0, 0) in the x-y plane. After an
> import turtle, give it the command turtle.forward(15), and it moves
> (on-screen!) 15 pixels in the direction it is facing, drawing a line
> as it moves.

As far as I know, turtle operates in units of screen pixels:

```
>>> from turtle import *
>>> print(position())
(0.00,0.00)
>>> forward(20)
>>> print(position())
(20.00,0.00)
>>>
```